# Code::Blocks - перейти к строке

Tags: ide, codeblocks

Продолжая темы про исследования Code::Blocks появился следующий вопрос:
как перейти к нужной строке в редакторе? типа `go to line`

Я понимаю что вопрос звучит идеотически, но я так и не смог отыскать это в меню :)

И про руссификацию, то что лежит на лаунчпаде не содержит примерно треть переводов, и меню с плагинами по факту отсутствует, посоветуйте рабочую версию, если не затруднит.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ctrl+G

Это стандартное "сокращение" (shortcut) для множества редакторов.

> The display of line numbers in CodeBlocks can be activated via ’Settings’ →’General
>   Settings’ in the field ’Show line numbers’. The shortcut **Ctrl-G** or the menu command
>   **’Search’ →’Goto line’** will help you jump to the desired line.

Comment: Спасибо, ещеб и русский язык в него пристроить..